# Bounds on the size of independent matching

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Suppose I have a graph $G = (V,E)$.

We will call $S \subset E$ an independent matching if $\forall \{a,b\},\{c,d\} \in S:~ \{a,b\} \cap (N(c) \cup N(d)) = \emptyset$, where $N(x) = \{x\} \cup \{y | \{x,y\} \in E\}$. In other words, $S$ is a set of edges in $G$ such that removing it will make set of endpoints of $S$ an independent set.

Do we have any known bounds on the size of the largest independent matching in a graph? I'm mostly interested in cases of bounded degree and average degree.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that $G$ is an undirected  graph with $m=|E|$ edges and the maximum degree $\Delta(G)$. Denote the size of the largest independent matching in a graph $G$ by $im(G)$. Consider a graph $ G^\sharp$ whose vertices are edges of $G$ and vertices $\{a,b\}\ne \{c,d\}$ of the graph $G^\sharp$ are adjacent iff $\{a,b\} \cap (N(c) \cup N(d)) = \emptyset$. Then clearly $im(G)=\alpha(G^\sharp)$,  where $\alpha(G^\sharp)$ is the size of the maximum independent subset of vertices of the graph $G^\sharp $. In particular, $$\alpha(G^\sharp)\ge\frac m{\chi(G^\sharp)}\ge \frac{m}{\Delta(G^\sharp)+1},$$ where  $\Delta(G^\sharp)$ is the maximum degree  of the graph $ G^\sharp$. It is easy to see that $$\Delta(G^\sharp)\le 2\Delta(G)^2-2\Delta(G)+1.$$ Finally we obtain an lower bound

$$im(G)\ge  \frac{m}{2(\Delta(G)^2-\Delta(G)+1)}.$$

Comment: Thanks! Do you think it's tight?

Comment: @ivmihajlin I don't know. I'll think about this.